# FFmpeg, preserve album cover when converting from MP3 to Opus (OGG)

Tags: ffmpeg, opus, cover

So basically I'm using FFmpeg Batch AV Converter (which is very good and I recommend) and I'm trying to convert all my music which is stored in FLAC, AAC and MP3 to Opus (OGG).

The problem is that I don't know what should I do so that the album cover is preserved in the conversion. As in, the metadata itself is copied to the Opus file, except the album cover.

Now of course I could  add it later with a metadata editor, but it's too much work and it may even be unnecessary if there is a command to do that.

I currently use:

```
-c:a libopus -b:a 128k -vbr on -compression_level 10 -frame_duration 20 -application audio
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg` does not yet support muxing album cover art in Opus.

See bug report [#4448: Support writing album cover art in ogg / opus](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4448).

Until it is fixed you'll have to use something else to add the album art, such as with `opusenc`.